# Short story about a ferris wheel ride to Mars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read a short story in 1969 high school English class. It had to do with buying a ticket to ride a ferris wheel, but the ride would actually go to Mars? Protagonist wrestles with desire to go vs fear to leave. I thought it was a Ray Bradbury story, but not at all certain.

Comment: Was the ticket a cover for a secret Mars mission, or was the Ferris wheel actually the means of travel?  Neil R. Jones had some aliens using a large wheel to spin a capsule at high speed, then release it so its momentum would carry it to a nearby planet, but that story didn't involve Mars.